# .play(); not working for html5 audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have been working on my javascript skills but I encountered a problem where the audio wasn't being played when clicked here is my code.

```
<div class="player_container">
<button class="play_pause_button" type="button" title="Play" onclick="play_pause"></button>
        <audio class="audio_player" preload="auto">
           <source src="audio/test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName('audio_player'),
    play_pause = document.getElementsByClassName('play_pause_button'),
    progress = document.getElementsByClassName('player_progress');
    function play_pause() {
        return content.play();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName('audio_player')` returns a HTMLCollection object and not an individual node. You need to specify which object in the collection you mean before sending commands to it.

Changing `return content.play();` to `return content[0].play();` should fix your problem.

Comment: @user2498606 testing the complete script in firefox it seem to have a problem with the underscore in your function name. remove the underscore and change `onclick="play_pause"` to `onclick="playpause()"`